# Page 404 error after running Django server

Tags: python, django

I have just started learning django and was trying to make a smartnotes App project by following a course.
I updated the setting.py file to add website into Instaled_Apps. Then have written a function named home in views.py
Finally I added it's entry into urls.py fie
"welcome.html is insdie homeApp/templates/home directory"
But when I run the server, I am getting following error on webpage:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpRequest


# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home/welcome.html', {})
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # apps that I created
    'home',
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import path
from home import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home', views.home),
]
```

**welcome.html**

````
    <title>
        welcome Page
    </title> </head> <body>
        <h1>Hello world !!!</h1>
        <h2>this is my first ever django project....</h2> </body> </html> ``` 



> **error its show is**
> 
> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/
> 
> Using the URLconf defined in smartappProject.urls, Django tried these
> URL patterns, in this order:
> 
>     admin/
>     home
> 
> The empty path didn’t match any of these.
````

Comment: Please, share what error is saying exactly.

Comment: this is the error it is showing me
Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in smartappProject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    home

The empty path didn’t match any of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your `urlpatterns`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home', views.home),
]
```

You haven't set the path for real "home" page, which should be `""`. Change it to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home),
]
```

And you will be fine. The first argument in parenthesis is real "value" that you need to provide just after the domain (`http://localhost:8000/` with local service).

Comment: thankyou is did the same its working when i remove the "home" and use "", but i am wondering why it is not showing me the page when i put the home url?

Comment: would you mind if you could explain it a little bit more?

Comment: Because it cannot find the path. `path('home', ...)` would work for "http://localhost:8000/home" and `path('stack_overflow', ...)` would work for "http://localhost:8000/stack_overflow". Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher